# Java: Is there a way to efficiently insert or remove many elements from the middle of a LinkedList?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I was expecting to find this in Java's LinkedList, since the point of linked lists is to be able to efficiently insert (and remove) anywhere (assuming you have some kind of pointer to the location where you want to insert or remove). I'm not finding anything in the API though. Am I overlooking something?

The closest thing I can find to this are the add and remove method in ListIterator. This has some limitations though. In particular, other iterators become invalid as soon as the underlying LinkedList is modified via remove, according to the API. This is born out in my tests as well; the following program results in a IllegalStateException:

```
import java.util.*;
public class RemoveFromLinkedList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Integer> myList= new LinkedList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            myList.add(i);
        }

        ListIterator<Integer> i1 = myList.listIterator();
        ListIterator<Integer> i2 = myList.listIterator();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            i1.next();
            i2.next();
        }

        System.out.println("i1.next() should be 3: " + i1.next());
        i1.remove();
        i1.remove();

        // Exception!
        System.out.println("i2.next() should be 5: " + i2.next());
    }
}
```

Ideally, what I'm expecting is something like this:

```
// In my imagination only. This is the way Java actually works, afaict.

// Construct two insertion/deletion points in LinkedList myLinkedList.
myIterator = myLinkedList.iterator();
for (...) {
 myIterator.next();
}
start = myIterator.clone();
for (...) {
 myIterator.next();
}

// Later...

after = myLinkedList.spliceAfter(myIterator, someOtherLinkedList);
// start, myIterator, and after are still all valid; thus, I can do this:
// Removes everything I just spliced in, as well as some other stuff before that.
myLinkedList.remove(start, after);
// Now, myIterator is invalid, but not start, nor after.
```

C++ has something like this for its [list](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/splice/) class (template). Only iterators pointing to moved elements become invalidated, not ALL iterators.

Comment: Do you really need to have a LinkedList? Is there lots of legacy code depending on this, or is this new code?

Comment: It's unclear whether you're looking for a solution that will allow you to insert/remove multiple elements from the linked list (as written in the title) or if you care about iterators getting invalidated (as written in the comment to my question).

Comment: @user946850 No, it doesn't need to be a linked list, but I think it's the most natural way to efficiently do the operations that I'm thinking of.

Comment: @Simon Iterators are just a means to an end. They are the "closest thing" that I've found so far.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution to remove a bunch of elements from a list while leaving several "running" iterators untouched? What should happen if current iterated item is removed? It looks for me like a transactional data source. Or you should use immutable lists and create a copy on every change.

Comment: There might be other implementations around that offer the operation you're looking for. Java's `LinkedList` just won't offer splitting, what a shame...

Comment: If you have specific needs you can always roll your own LinkedList... It's pretty easy after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With java.util.LinkedList, the only way to refer to locations in the list for later efficient manipulation is an Iterator, and Iterators are invalidated if the underlying list is modified by something other than this Iterator.

If you really need that capability, you'll have to look beyond the Java API, or write it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove something with an iterator you cann still continue to use that same iterator. It's possible to do

```
iterator.remove();
iterator.next();
iterator.remove();
iterator.next();
```

That's the closest thing as far as I know.

Comment: Yes, I understand that iterator itself does not become invalidated, but all other iterators do. This point is central to my question.

Comment: And as a sidenote: I found that Java's LinkedLists are pretty slow. These days linked lists are often slow (cache). In most cases ArrayLists are way faster, even if you have to remove stuff from the middle every now and then. If you can batch operations, it's even quicker.

Comment: Well, if LinkedList doesn't have the ability to to insert or remove whole swaths, then it's not a fair comparison; LinkedLists SHOULD have this ability.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't realize you realized that you could delete multiple elements with a single Iterator. I'm afraid, there's no way (that I know of) to access the structure concurrently with multiple iterators. You'll probably have to find around it. As written before, batching can help performance.

Comment: @allyourcode: LinkedLists do have this ability. You can remove multiple elements with a single iterator or you can add multiple elements (see `addAll`). It's just that iterators are no longer usable when the underlying data structures are modified.

Comment: re remove: Yes, but you can only remove one at a time instead of all at once (not as efficient as it could be), and all other iterators become invalid (a pretty big limitation, if you have a bunch of iterators).

Comment: re addAll: You can only append, or insert at an index. Presumably, with an index, you have to scan through the list, which isn't efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can do funny things with `List.subList(startIndex, endIndex)`. With this you can clear a whole range in the "source" list. You can also use `addAll` at the sublist to insert new stuff into the source list.

If `LinkedList` has an efficient implementation for this - I don't know.

Comment: Nice idea, the implementation however is not as good as it could be. A look at the source shows that more often than not `toArray` is getting called...

Comment: @Simon: I already told you, that the efficiency is unknown :-) The bonus of `subList` is the brevity and clarity of the code.

Comment: Eh?  Where is `toArray` getting called?  `subList` returns a view; it doesn't copy the collection.

Comment: `subList().addAll()` calls `LinkedList.addAll(index, list)`. This in turn calls `list.toArray`. When not inserting at the start or end of the list `addAll` searches the insertion point by iterating either from the start or from the end of the list. This means that the insertion point found by `sublist` is recalculated.